# Strange behavior with float textures in ANGLE WebGL implementation

Tags: webgl

I'm using floating point textures in my app to store the data and i've been noticing that in ANGLE WebGL, when i store, for example, a Float32Array([ a, b, c, d ]), the data occupies 4 nearest quad texels and each of these texels contains the values divided by 4:

```
r = a / 4
g = b / 4
b = c / 4
a = d / 4
```

In OpenGL WebGL implementation (Linux and Windows) everything behave as expected: 1 texel contains RGBA values which i provide.

Have anybody faced that? Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

This happens with anisotropic filtering enabled, if someone interested =) ANGLE is OK!